# How i can know my site has very good performnce using jmeter?

Tags: performance, load, jmeter, performance-testing, web-testing

Please give me instructions about j-meter, how can i test performance of my site that its response is good and it can bear 500 to 1000 users at same time. Also please give me scenarios that can be performed to test performance of my site.
I have tested my site using j-meter but i cannot understand what these results means. Kindly tell me some perfect/final result (Response time, throughput, mean time, etc) of some sites which have good performance so that if those results come to me  i will be satisfied that i am going well. 
What should be avg response time, throughput, deviation, median, mean etc for a website normally?
Thanks

Comment: What you're asking, is a whole book if answered properly. The format of this site wont produce a useful answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

While load testing,you have to take help of some tools that will perform resource monitoring.

like in java , there is jvisualV
-- You may take help of jvisualvm path of this tool is Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\jvisualvm.exe

You may use it to determine your cpu utilization and memory consumption.

[image]

Hope it may help you.